# In MigraDoc, how do I surround some text and a table with the same border?

Tags: c#, migradoc

Using MigraDoc, I'm able to write a sentence (in a single paragraph) and follow it with a table. I would like to surround both of these with a single outer border (the table should still have its own border). I tried creating a text frame, adding the text and table, and setting the border for the frame, but that didn't work (the text was in the border but the table was not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would use a single table, maybe with some dummy columns and/or dummy rows.

You can add a row between "paragraph" and "table". You can add dummy columns left and right and below "table" to get a double border here.

For the "paragraph" you can use MergeRight to have it span all columns.

Most likely you will have to add two rows at the top, one row at the bottom, one column at the left, one column at the right. And "table" header will not be repeated if "table" should break across two pages.

Comment: Thank you! I had to play a lot with the indents and paddings to make things look right, but it worked! Too bad about the table header not repeating if the table breaks across two pages.